# Conflicting commands in preamble

Tags: hyperref, incompatibility, ieeetran

I am using the class IEEEtran for writing a journal. I have two conflicting commands in my preamble. The first command has been used by me for some time, though I have no idea why it should be there. As far as I know, it is to resolve some bug with IEEEtran. The first command is

```
\newcommand{\theHalgorithm}{\thechapter.\arabic{algorithm}}
```

The second command is

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

The moment I include the package (either before or after first command) *hyperref*, it exits with an error.

```
Paragraph ended before \Hy@setref@link was complete
```

Can anyone explain to me what is happening.

Comment: What happens if you do not use the first command?

Comment: hyperref works normally and I can't find any difference.

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reprodcuces the problem.  While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: The following does _not_ have a problem so it must be somethign else in your preamble and hence a MWE woudl be good: `\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\theHalgorithm}{\thechapter.\arabic{algorithm}}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}`

Comment: You shouldn't need `hyperref` for an IEEE journal since all the links are handled by the publication office including DOI and other mail addresses. So indeed a MWE is required.